# "Uncaught Error: Class 'Magento\Setup\Mvc\Bootstrap\InitParamListener' not found" error on fresh install

Tags: php, web, magento

I am working on a website migration, so I did a new CI/CD pipeline, which uses compsoer to install magento and merge it with custom pub directory. The problem I have, is, when I do the `php bin/magento setup:install` command, I receive following error :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Magento\Setup\Mvc\Bootstrap\InitParamListener' not found in /htdocs/releases/20231116163606/setup/config/application.config.php:29
Stack trace:
#0 /htdocs/releases/20231116163606/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(78): require()
#1 /htdocs/releases/20231116163606/bin/magento(22): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->__construct()
#2 {main}
  thrown in /htdocs/releases/20231116163606/setup/config/application.config.php on line 29
```

I have been reading forums for hours and I do not manage to get out of this. Magento project-community-edition version 2.4.2.

I did try removing my setup / vendor folders and then doing again the composer install or update, but this doesn't change anything. I tried going on 2.4.6 version, still same error.

I did try removing these folders `bin dev generated lib phpserver setup var vendor` and still same errors.

Note, this is the only magento website we have in my org, so I'm really not familiar with it.

Does anyone have an idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please Go to the root directory and remove the vendor folder:

rm -rf vendor

Then run the composer install command. Please check the below command

composer install

Comment: Hello, I literally said in the post, that I already did this